# How to export unity project to play in HTC Vive?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I have an Unity project which I want to export and use in HTC Vive. How do I do that and in addition is there any resource online which I can use to refer how do I code to use the controllers for HTC Vive?

Answer (score 4):

*So here is the answer for your different parts of questions(also for beginner VR developer with unity and HTC-Vive):*

1. **Instead of exporting your project into HTC Vive project** you are required to import Free [**SteamVR Official Plugin**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/steamvr-plugin-32647) into your project.  After exporting the plugin, you can bring **CameraRig** prefab (*from the prefab folder of the plugin*) into you main scene project in order to view it through your HTC Vive head set. (its simple, now you can watch your project through htc-vive)
2. If you are familiar with Unity and C# then you can easily work with VR. For Object interaction in VR & different purposes here comes the lovely [**VRTK - SteamVR Unity Toolkit**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/vrtk-virtual-reality-toolkit-vr-toolkit-64131). Its amazing, you can import it in to your project. It provides ***40 demo Scenes*** that defines different things like object interaction, door interaction or teleportation, movement etc etc. Simply you require to import the package and explore its demo scenes to understand it. It also provide very healthy [**documentation**](https://github.com/thestonefox/VRTK).
3. If you looking exactly for object interaction with your **Vive controller** you are required *Interactable Objec*t script in your object. [You can follow its details here](https://academy.vrtk.io/Documentation/HowToGuides/Interactions/AddingAnInteractable/)

So it is simple, you require [SteamVR](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/steamvr-plugin-32647) (its essential) and [VRTK](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/vrtk-virtual-reality-toolkit-vr-toolkit-64131) (its optional - to make VR development easy) in order to bring HTC-Vive application development into reality. (VRTK make HTC-vive development more simple and easy, thanks to VRTK team).

Comment: Additional links: [Steam-VR-ToolKit on GitHub](https://github.com/prefectover/Steam-VR-ToolKit) / [SteamVR on Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/250820/SteamVR/) / 
[SteamVR Unity Plugin](https://valvesoftware.github.io/steamvr_unity_plugin/)

Comment: @daire43 No need to propose an edit, those links are already posted as comments here. From 2-3 years ago.